# Excel Writing results in Read-Error

Tags: java, linux, excel, jxl

I have some code that writes into an Excel file:

```
File file = new File("Path here");
File to = new File("Path here");
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
WritableWorkbook target = Workbook.createWorkbook(to);
target.createSheet("s", 0);
Sheet source = workbook.getSheet(1);
WritableSheet targetSheet = target.getSheet(0);
copyRow(source, 1, targetSheet, 1);
workbook.close();
target.close();
```

Note that `Path here` is replaced with the actual path in the real code.

Where the `copyRow()` method looks like this:

```
private void copyRow(Sheet sourceSheet, int sourceRow, WritableSheet targetSheet, int targetRow) throws WriteException {
    for(int i = 0, numOfColumn = sourceSheet.getColumns(); i < numOfColumn; i++) {
        Cell source = sourceSheet.getCell(i, sourceRow);
        WritableCell cell = new Label(i, targetRow, source.getContents());
        targetSheet.addCell(cell);
    }
}
```

It runs, but when I try to open the `to` file:

[image: Read-error]

An error message, saying that the file cannot be opened, shows when I use my Windows computer to open the same file.

Why does that happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't see you calling `target.write()` anywhere.  You're also not closing `to`.

Comment: @adamdc78 I do call `target.addCell()`, though. Also, where do I close `to`?

Comment: [Java Code Example for jxl.WritableWorkbook](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=jxl.write.WritableWorkbook) uses `addCell()` and then `write()`.  `addCell()` is for the sheet, not the workbook.  You wouldn't close `to`, ignore that.